# Unable to configure SMTP for Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I have crated `Cloud Build` ***triggers*** to create ***CI/CD*** pipeline for a project and its working perfectly fine. Now, I want to configure `SMTP` notifications so the entire project team can have updates on the status of build.

`Cloud Build` publishes ***status*** of build to `Cloud Pub/Sub` ***topic*** `cloud-build`. So to achieve this I have been following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-smtp) published by Google Cloud.

I have done exactly what the document says -

1. Enabled required APIs.
2. Created a secret to store my SMTP credentials.
3. Gave permission to `Compute Engine` default service account to access created secret.
4. Wrote a notifier configuration as documented.

```
apiVersion: cloud-build-notifiers/v1
kind: SMTPNotifier
metadata:
  name: master-deloyed-to-staging.
spec:
  notification:
    filter: build.status == Build.Status.SUCCESS
    delivery:
      server: smtp.gmail.com
      port: '587'
      sender: r@gmail.com
      from: r@gmail.com
      recipients:
      - a@gmail.com
      - b@gmail.com
      - c@gmail.com
      - d@gmail.com
      - e@gmail.com
      password:
        secretRef: dropoff-gmail
  secrets:
  - name: dropoff-gmail
    value: projects/project-id/secrets/secret-name/versions/latest
```

5. Created a bucked and uploaded the `smtp-notifier.yaml` to it.
6. Now this is the stage where I prepared a command to deploy `notifier` to `cloud run` -

```
 gcloud run deploy dropoff-deployment-notifier \
   --image=us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/gcb-release/cloud-build-notifiers/smtp:latest \
   --update-env-vars=CONFIG_PATH=gs://dropoff-assets/cloud_run/smtp-notifier.yaml
```

and that returns me an error -

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

As, stated in error something is wrong with the PORT but know how to fix it.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it did not apply. I followed the steps of the documentation guide and found the same error.

Comment: I found how to solve my issue, which could be different than yours.

Comment: You'll have to go to the logs in the Cloud Console > Logging > Cloud Run Revision, find the latest and see what is the error of the first entry showing.

Comment: @Juancki Checked the cloud run logs it shows the same error.

Comment: There should be multiple entries, on my logs, the last error is the not listening on PORT error, and the first entry showed the container build error.